# Is there a better way to say "did you find yourself here unexpectedly"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

I was preparing a title and I had decided to go with *Oh, no! Stumbled upon the void?*

since its a title for the web that I decided to go without the "Did you stumble" part.

But when I looked up in the dictionary I understood that stumble upon doesn't convey the meaning.

> Definition of stumble across/on/onto/upon
> : to find or learn about (something) unexpectedly
> I stumbled across/on/upon this book by chance.
> We stumbled onto/across the ruins of an old fort.
> They stumbled on/upon a bizarre plot.
> He stumbled onto the truth.

So is there a better way than to say *Oh, no! Stumbled upon the void?*

Comment: This is not a creative writing site. Sorry.

Comment: should I ask this at writing stackexchange?
english is my second language and I'm in process of improving it, thats why I asked here.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, It's just that it's a style question, which is a matter of opinion and therefore not encouraged here, unfortunately. . It's fine as far as the grammar goes, But I am not sure it's a good title....Personally, I don't like titles that leave out bits of phrases as we do when talking. [Do you] feel me? :)

Comment: Thank you, now its clear for me. I'm reconsidering whether to leave out the "did you" part after your comment. Thanks for both.

Comment: No worries. If this were my site, I'd allow all sorts of questions that are currently frowned upon. There is a writing/writers' site as well around here.

Comment: Are you trying to say something like "found the void" or "hurt my toe on the void"?

Comment: In addition to answering @Peter question you might also like to explain why the first part is an exclamation but the second is a question.

Comment: @Peter, the context: the text is for a 404 not found page https://www.ashtamangalaprasnam.com/404. 
So I was thinking of doing something creative and decided to show the starts and ask user if he's in the void. 


*I'm not a UX copywriter but a developer with intentions of improving my English.*

Comment: @mdewey, should this be "Oh, Did you stumble upon the void!"

Comment: Titles these days often need to be short. What about just "The Void"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we have the context that this is for a 404 page I can see that your original suggestion

> Oh, no! Stumbled on the void?

would work although I might have replaced *on* with *into*. Since we know by this point that they have reached a non-existent page I might have used

> Oh, no! You seem to have stumbled into the void.